# How to get the list of class that have a common S4 superclass in R

Tags: r, subclass, superclass, r-s4

In R, how do I get the list of subclass of a S4 superclass?

I found showClass("mySuperClass",complete=FALSE) but it only prints the result. I would like to store it in a vector to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discover the class of a class definition (the class definition is itself an S4 class!)

```
cls = getClass("MySuperClass")
class(cls)
class?classRepresentation
```

and, with a little exploring, arrive at

```
names(cls@subclasses)
```